# Cannot Serialize JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to access data from a json at this url : http://na.lolesports.com/api/gameStatsFantasy.json?tournamentId=104.

I used a website called http://json2csharp.com/ to help create classes to serialize. It worked but I noticed the JSON had many duplicate instances of the same gameID, playerID and teamID(e.g one named Game2998 and Game29982 or team4 and team42).

```
 public class RootObject
{
    public TeamStats teamStats { get; set; }
    public PlayerStats playerStats { get; set; }
}
public class TeamStats
{
    public Dictionary<string, Game>  GameID { get; set; }
}
public class PlayerStats
{
    public Dictionary<string,game> gameID { get; set; }
}
public class Game
{
    public string dateTime { get; set; }
    public Team blueTeam { get; set; }
    public Team purpleTeam { get; set; }
    public string matchId { get; set; }
}
public class game
{
    public string dateTime { get; set; }
    public string matchId { get; set; }
    public Player bluePlayer1 { get; set; }
    public Player bluePlayer2 { get; set; }
    public Player bluePlayer3 { get; set; }
    public Player bluePlayer4 { get; set; }
    public Player bluePlayer5 { get; set; }
    public Player purplePlayer1 { get; set; }
    public Player purplePlayer2 { get; set; }
    public Player purplePlayer3 { get; set; }
    public Player purplePlayer4 { get; set; }
    public Player purplePlayer5 { get; set; }
}
public class Player
{
        public int playerId { get; set; }
        public int kills { get; set; }
        public int deaths { get; set; }
        public int assists { get; set; }
        public int minionKills { get; set; }
        public int doubleKills { get; set; }
        public int tripleKills { get; set; }
        public int quadraKills { get; set; }
        public int pentaKills { get; set; }
        public string playerName { get; set; }
        public string role { get; set; }

}
public class Team
{
    public int teamId { get; set; }
    public string teamName { get; set; }
    public int matchVictory { get; set; }
    public int matchDefeat { get; set; }
    public int baronsKilled { get; set; }
    public int dragonsKilled { get; set; }
    public int firstBlood { get; set; }
    public int firstTower { get; set; }
    public int firstInhibitor { get; set; }
    public int towersKilled { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tend to use JavaScriptSerializer . It's built into .Net

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry I was out the door and was in a rush to ask a question to hopefully be answered by the time I got home from work.

Comment: Still no question, are you just asking why you're getting duplicates from that site?

Comment: No, It's not that. I've finally figured out the structure of the JSON but still the JSON is a mess and I am having trouble converting it into a c# object.

Comment: Recommend closing or deleting this question.  It is a duplicate of [Can anyone assist me in deserializing my JSON to C# Objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908172/can-anyone-assist-me-in-deserializing-my-json-to-c-sharp-objects) asked by the same user.  The other question has an accepted answer.