# Can anyone assist me in deserializing my JSON to C# Objects?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to convert JSON to Objects to easily accesses statistics. I currently get a null value for my Dictionary and Dictionary. If anybody could help it would be much appreciated.

Here is an example of my JSON:

```
    {
"teamStats": {
    "game2998": {
        "dateTime": "2014-05-23T19:00Z",
        "team304": {
            "teamId": 304,
            "teamName": "Cloud9 ",
            "matchVictory": 1,
            "matchDefeat": 0,
            "baronsKilled": 2,
            "dragonsKilled": 4,
            "firstBlood": 0,
            "firstTower": 0,
            "firstInhibitor": 1,
            "towersKilled": 10
        },
        "team1": {
            "teamId": 1,
            "teamName": "Team SoloMid",
            "matchVictory": 0,
            "matchDefeat": 1,
            "baronsKilled": 0,
            "dragonsKilled": 1,
            "firstBlood": 1,
            "firstTower": 1,
            "firstInhibitor": 0,
            "towersKilled": 5
        },
        "matchId": "2515"
    }
},
"playerStats": {
    "game2998": {
        "dateTime": "2014-05-23T19:00Z",
        "matchId": "2515",
        "player328": {
            "playerId": 328,
            "kills": 1,
            "deaths": 1,
            "assists": 7,
            "minionKills": 254,
            "doubleKills": 0,
            "tripleKills": 0,
            "quadraKills": 0,
            "pentaKills": 0,
            "playerName": "Balls",
            "role": "Top Lane"
        },
        "player329": {
            "playerId": 329,
            "kills": 4,
            "deaths": 0,
            "assists": 7,
            "minionKills": 155,
            "doubleKills": 1,
            "tripleKills": 0,
            "quadraKills": 0,
            "pentaKills": 0,
            "playerName": "Meteos",
            "role": "Jungler"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is an example of my classes:

```
 public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, GameT> teamStats { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, GameP> playerStats { get; set; }
}

public  class GameT
{
    public string dateTime { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, Team> blueTeam { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, Team> purpleTeam { get; set; }
    public string matchId { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int teamId { get; set; }
    public string teamName { get; set; }
    public int matchVictory { get; set; }
    public int matchDefeat { get; set; }
    public int baronsKilled { get; set; }
    public int dragonsKilled { get; set; }
    public int firstBlood { get; set; }
    public int firstTower { get; set; }
    public int firstInhibitor { get; set; }
    public int towersKilled { get; set; }
}
public class GameP
{
    public string dateTime { get; set; }
    public string matchId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Player> blueTop { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Player> blueJungle { get; set; }




}
public class Player
{
    public int playerId { get; set; }
        public int kills { get; set; }
        public int deaths { get; set; }
        public int assists { get; set; }
        public int minionKills { get; set; }
        public int doubleKills { get; set; }
        public int tripleKills { get; set; }
        public int quadraKills { get; set; }
        public int pentaKills { get; set; }
        public string playerName { get; set; }
        public string role { get; set; }

}
```

Screen shot of my null issues:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IC3g.gif

Comment: that json scheme is *not* exactly considerate towards serialization/deserialization; is there no option to make the json more sane?

Comment: the json which you have put it here is not valid

Comment: I am retrieving the Json from an API and the Json itself is a huge mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your JSON has the team and player lists mixed in with the game attributes (date and match ID), you will need to use a custom `JsonConverter` to make it work with strongly typed dictionaries in your classes.  I'll explain how you can do this below.

First, define your classes like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, Game<Team>> teamStats { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Game<Player>> playerStats { get; set; }
}

public class Game<T>
{
    public string dateTime { get; set; }
    public string matchId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, T> items { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int teamId { get; set; }
    public string teamName { get; set; }
    public int matchVictory { get; set; }
    public int matchDefeat { get; set; }
    public int baronsKilled { get; set; }
    public int dragonsKilled { get; set; }
    public int firstBlood { get; set; }
    public int firstTower { get; set; }
    public int firstInhibitor { get; set; }
    public int towersKilled { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public int playerId { get; set; }
    public int kills { get; set; }
    public int deaths { get; set; }
    public int assists { get; set; }
    public int minionKills { get; set; }
    public int doubleKills { get; set; }
    public int tripleKills { get; set; }
    public int quadraKills { get; set; }
    public int pentaKills { get; set; }
    public string playerName { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
}
```

Define a generic JsonConverter which can handle the "Game" part of the JSON, separating the date and match ID from the rest of the items:

```
public class GameConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Game<T>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        Game<T> game = new Game<T>();
        game.dateTime = jo["dateTime"].ToString();
        game.matchId = jo["matchId"].ToString();
        game.items = new Dictionary<string, T>();
        foreach (JProperty prop in jo.Properties())
        {
            if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
            {
                game.items.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value.ToObject<T>());
            }
        }
        return game;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

With the converter in place, you can deserialize as follows (note we need two instances of the converter, one to handle the list of teams and one to handle the list of players):

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new GameConverter<Team>());
settings.Converters.Add(new GameConverter<Player>());

RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json, settings);
```

Comment: Amazing. Simply amazing. I feel like I was on the right track but never once thought about a class of Game<T> or to use a custom JsonConverter. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have no attribute called blueTeam nor purpleTeam inside your JSON.

Maybe it should look like that:

```
    "teamStats": {
        "game2998": {
            "dateTime": "2014-05-23T19:00Z",
            "blueTeam": {
                "team304": {
                    "teamId": 304,
                    [...]
            }},
            "purpleTeam": {
                "team1": {
                    "teamId": 1,
                    [...]
            }},
            "matchId": "2515"
        }
```

Comment: So my classes do not match the Json which I understand. So I need to get rid of blueTeam and purpleTeam. But here is my next question. In my classes do I have to declare a Dictionary for EVERY team and EVERY player? public Dictionary<string, Team> team304 {get; set} public Dictionary<string, Team> team1 { get; set}.

This seems impossible because there is different teams playing in different games.